# How to convert Array Of Object A to Array Of Object B with Constructor of A Using Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have two Classes Class A and Class B. As below:

**Class A:**

```
class A {

  public String a;

  public A() {

  }

  public A(final String a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

**Class B:**

```
class B {

  private A a;

  private String b;

  public B() {

  }

  public B(final A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Where I am converting A[] to B[] as below:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final A[] myA = new A[3];
    myA[0] = new A("a");
    myA[1] = new A("b");
    myA[2] = new A("c");
    
    B[] myB = new B[myA.length];

    IntStream.range(0, myA.length).forEach(propIndex->{
      myB[propIndex] = new B(myA[propIndex]);
    });

    System.out.println(myB.length);
}
```

Is there any other way to do it without iterating(`forEach`) with Index? Something with `toArray(B[]::new)` or any other way where I don't have to use `forEach`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
B[] myB = Arrays.stream(myA) // create a Stream<A>
                .map(B::new) // map each instance of A to instance of B
                .toArray(B[]::new); // collect to array of B
```

Answer (score 2):

IntStream is not the worst, though an iterative transfer with a regular loop would probably be faster here (though arguably less readable).

```java
B[] myB = new B[myA.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myA.length; ++i) {
  myB[i] = new B(myA[i]);
}
```